# Xamarin.Android Layout Issues - Title Bar Icon

Tags: android, android-layout, xamarin

I have an Android app developed with Eclipse/IntelliJ (yes, I used both so I could compare them) which I have now ported to Xamarin.Android (again, so I could compare).

Everything is functional in the Xamarin port, but one thing I have noticed are some discrepancies in how the layouts are presented.  I haven't yet been able to nail them down, but they generally consist of handling default behaviors differently.  So cases where I don't specify widths, or colors but instead use "wrap-content"/"match_parent" or, in the case of colors, don't explicitly specify a text color (for example).

I'm curious, first, if anyone else has seen this, why this would be and if there's a fix so that the same layout could be used across platforms.

I also have a second issue which is that of trying to display an image and label in the title bar.

In the java app AndroidManifest.xml, I have:

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"...
```

and in the xamarin AndroidManifest.xml, I have:

```
<application
    android:label="TnTM"
    android:icon="@drawable/icon">...
```

and in AssemblyInfo.cs:

```
[assembly: AssemblyTitle("TnTA")]
```

Finally, there is the main activity itself, which has the following:

```
[Activity(Label = "TnTC", Icon = "@drawable/icon")]
```

The final value being the one displayed in the Title Bar. However, there is no image appearing.

So, in addition to my questions about the differing layouts, what drives the title bar label (are all those other values ignored?) and image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick here is that with Eclipse/IntelliJ, the features seem to be ruled by the emulator deployed to, while Xamarin is driven by the target API level.

So, building with IntelliJ, targeting api level 10, but deploying to an api level 17 emulator gave me api level 17 features. Doing the same with Xamarin gave me api level 10 features. Changing the target sdk to 17 allowed the icon to be displayed.

It's too bad they're not consistent and I'm not sure which behavior I prefer, but I'm glad to finally have an explanation.